# How to decide whether and where to publish your research?

Tags: publications, mathematics, publishability

I am writing my thesis in applied mathematics.

I developed two numerical schemes that seem to have practical applications in many fields and certainly have bright prospect for mathematical software.
I checked many existing resources and could not find anything similar or better.

How do I find out if this worth publishing? And if so how do I find the journal?

Answer (score 5):

You're lucky:

> I am writing my thesis

If you're writing your thesis, you have a thesis advisor. They would be extremely well-placed to answer your questions - not only do they know your work well, they have a vested interest in seeing you succeed. They are also well-placed to act as your mentors in academic issues such as this.

You can ask them both about whether it's worth publishing and where to publish it, and what they say will likely be a better answer than anything an outsider can write.

Comment: @NotaChoice Why don't you trust them? Why have an advisor you don't trust? Instead of a professor in the field you work in who is closely familiar with your specific work, why rely on internet strangers who aren't in your field and don't know your work?

Comment: @NotaChoice If you don't trust your advisor enough to ask them these kind of questions you have much bigger issues than finding out whether and where your ideas could be published. How do you plan to write a thesis with this advisor?

Comment: I deleted my earlier comments as I used the wrong word, I meant but what if I don't believe them, trust is no issue.

Comment: @NotaChoice you should believe them because they're much more likely to be right than wrong. If you are *really* skeptical I suppose you could ask another professor in your department whether your supervisor is right (or ask another question here), I guess.